# Error estimate for interpolation polynomial using derivative

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Let $f$ be a $C^2[x_0,x_1]$ function and consider the interpolation polynomial of degree $1$
$$p(x_0)=f(x_0)\quad p'(x_1)=f'(x_1)$$
find the error $f(x)-p(x)$ for $x\in[x_0,x_1]$.

I found the polynomial by differentiating $p(x)=ax+b$ and it's
$$p(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_1)(x-x_0)$$
now this looks like the linear term of the taylor series about $x_0$ but that would require $f'(x_0)$. How do I estimate the error for this polynomial? is there a general way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to estimate error in this kind of situation is to choose any $x\in(x_0,x_1)$ and then set
$$e(y)=f(y)-p(y)-\frac{\left(x_1-y\right)^2-\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2}{\left(x_1-x\right)^2-\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2}\left(f(x)-p(x)\right)$$
Then $e\left(x_0\right)=f\left(x_0\right)-p\left(x_0\right)=0$, $e(x)=f(x)-p(x)-\left(f(x)-p(x)\right)=0$, and $e^{\prime}\left(x_1\right)=f^{\prime}\left(x_1\right)-p^{\prime}\left(x_1\right)=0$, so by Rolles' theorem there is some $c\in\left(x_0,x\right)$ such that $e^{\prime}(c)=0$. Then a further application of Rolles' theorem tells us that there is some $\xi\in\left(c,x_1\right)\subset\left(x_0,x_1\right)$ such that
$$e^{\prime\prime}(\xi)=f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)-\frac{2!}{\left(x_1-x\right)^2-\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2}\left(f(x)-p(x)\right)=0$$
Thus for any $x\in\left(x_0,x_1\right)$ there is some $\xi\in\left(x_0,x_1\right)$ such that
$$f(x)=p(x)+\frac{\left(x_1-x\right)^2-\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$$
The key step was finding a nontrivial polynomial of degree one higher than the interpolating polynomial that matched all the boundary conditions for the function $f(x)=0$. Once you've got that the rest follows mechanically.

**EDIT** Since the first derivative was also matched there might be some question about the error in the first derivative. To resolve this issue we take the first derivatives of the numerator and denominator functions of $x$ to get
$$g(y)=f(y)-p(y)+\frac{\left(x_1-y\right)^2-\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2}{2\left(x_1-x\right)}\left(f^{\prime}(x)-p^{\prime}(x)\right)$$
So that $g\left(x_0\right)=g^{\prime}(x)=g^{\prime}\left(x_1\right)=0$ and it follows directly that
$$f^{\prime}(x)=p^{\prime}(x)-\left(x_1-x\right)f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$$
For any $x\in\left(x_0,x_1\right)$ for some $\xi\in\left(x,x_1\right)$.

Comment: Thank you I understand it. Are there any tips for constructing such a polynomial?

Comment: For points where you match the $0^{\text{th}}$ through $n^{\text{th}}$ derivatives, like $x_0$ in this example, just supply a factor of $\left(x-x_0\right)^{n+1}$. For points where you skip a derivative, like $x_1$ above, life is more complicated. For situations like the Taylor polynomial or interpolation, including Hermite interpolation, the product of the easy factors does it, but in your problem above I multiplied the easy factor by an unknown polynomial of degree number of conditions not covered by the easy factor and used derivative conditions to determine the unknown.

Comment: I just noticed that you added the error in the derivative, thank you! Something like that was actually on the exam :)